# attach onClick handler to populated list item reactjs

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, frontend

i have a function that i want to fire when a button is being clicked, this button is included in a list item that gets populated based on values from an array passed from the parent component, but its not working and returning an error saying that the function is undefined, how can i make this work?

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Card extends React.Component {

constructor(){
  super()
  this.state = {
    index: null
  };
}

handleClick(x){
   this.setState({
    index: x
   })

}

 render(){
  /**
   * Populates list items according to data passed
   * on to resultsArray.
   */
    var items = this.props.resultsArray;
    var itemslist = items.map(function(item, index){
          return(
              <li key={ index } class="card" >
                <div class="card-header">
                    <span class="hour-price"><span>{ item.hourPrice } &euro; /hour</span></span>
                    <img src={ item.image } class="card-img" />
                    <a href="javascript:" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, {index})} class="book-button">Book</a>
                  </div>
                <div>
                  <div class="card-info">
                    <p class="workplace-name">{ item.name }</p>
                    <span class="score">{ item.score } &#9733;</span>
                    <p class="location">{ item.location }</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-footer">
                    <p class="price">{ item.price } &euro; / Day</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
          );})
    return(
      <div class="results-container">
        <ul class="card-list center">
          { itemslist }
         </ul>
      </div>   
      );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your `render` to the below codes. Use `that` instead of `this`.

```
var items = this.props.resultsArray;
var that = this;
var itemslist = items.map(function(item, index){
      return(
          <li key={ index } className="card" >
            <div className="card-header">
                <span className="hour-price"><span>{ item.hourPrice } &euro; /hour</span></span>
                <img src={ item.image } className="card-img" />
                <a href="javascript:" onClick={that.handleClick.bind(that, index)} className="book-button">Book</a>
            </div>
           ......
```

Comment: The `x` parameter is not in scope

Comment: @RedMercury. My mistake. I have changed the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @RedMercury do you have a solution ?

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried `onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)}` ? Arrow functions dont have a `this` context and use the one in their parent scope so there is no need for `bind`.

Comment: @RedMercury tried it now and its not working, actually the solution provided by Jason is working !

Comment: @Jason on a re run , the x parameter does not get recognized, how to solve this?

Comment: @user3209048 can you give me the specific error messages of your console?

Comment: @Jason i have done these changes but somehow x is always returned as 0 despite having 6 list items with ids 0 to 5

Comment: handleClick(){
  var x;
  x = $('.book-button').closest('li').attr('id');
   this.setState({
    index: x
   })
   console.log(this.state.index);
   console.log(x);

}

Comment: @Jason  <a href="javascript:"  onClick={that.handleClick.bind(that)} class="book-button">Book</a>

Comment: @Jason basically what i am trying to do is when i click on that button it opens a modal that shows more information about a specific list item, and so i need the index for that to retrieve the relevant data from the array

Comment: @user3209048 I have changed my answer to fix the issue. The direct reason is that you should pass `index` to `handleClick` instead of `{index}`.Besides, you should change all `class` to `className` to make your `css styles` work.

Comment: @Jason thank you very much it is working now perfectly, and fyi ii use a plugin to allow me to use class instead of className